# Finding similarity between Arabic text

Tags: plsql, nlp, oracle12c

I'm currently working on an Oracle 12c database production and on this production on of the tables contain about 2 millions record and the table contain a **name** column which contain both Arabic and English text. what I'm trying to do is to find a way to analyze the **name** column to get all the rows with similar to a given name. i tried using the `utl_match` package with contain implementation for *edit_distance* and *jaro_winkler* but this don't work perfectly for Arabic text since there are more similar letters in Arabic which the algorithm treats the as totally different letters like (أ, ا, إ) which results inefficient results. so what I'm looking for now is something to normalize the Arabic text, so i can use it with the `utl_match` package or any alternative which can help me do the job.
the task should be done in **PL/SQl** but if it's impossible I'm open to use any other tool or ideas

Answer (score 1):

Use the `TRANSLATE` function before `UTL_MATCH`.

For example, the initial edit distance is 2:

```
select
    utl_match.edit_distance
    (
        s1 => text1,
        s2 => text2
    ) edit_distance
from
(
    select
        'ليونيكود أاإ' text1,
        'ليونيكود ااا' text2
    from dual
);
```

After manually translating similar characters into the exact same character, the edit distance is now 0:

```
select
    utl_match.edit_distance
    (
        s1 => translate(text1, 'أإ', 'اا'),
        s2 => translate(text2, 'أإ', 'اا')
    ) edit_distance
from
(
    select
        'ليونيكود أاإ' text1,
        'ليونيكود ااا' text2
    from dual
);
```

There might be a better, more official way to compare strings using NLS settings and tools, but if there's only a few characters causing an issue, it's simpler to use `TRANSLATE`.

Comment: thanks @Jon Heller this is the solution i currently have but i'm looking for any other ideas and it would be great if you can mention 1 or 2 of these NLS tools which may help